# Android what is a toolchain compatibility issue?

Tags: android, x86, arm, toolchain, build-script

When porting an ARM native application to x86 platforms, Intel say:

> Toolchain Compatibility
>
> It is possible that your build environment uses the toolchain directly
>   instead of using the Android* build scripts. In the case of ARM* the
>   path used is:
>
> android-ndk\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3 For x86 use the
>   path: android-ndk\toolchains\x86-4.4.3 For more information see the
>   NDK document located in android-ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html.

However from this short description I do not understand what a toolchain compatibility issue is. I was wondering if someone could explain to me in a bit more detail what a toolchain compatibility issue is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do a google search on NDK toolchain and find a lot of information. It has to do with your compile and your target system. See http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html

Answer (score 1):

What that may imply is if your project uses Makefiles or some other solution to produce binaries which invokes gcc via a certain path, you need to update that to produce x86 compatible binaries. Think if your project uses some external libraries etc, then you need to make sure your build system creates x86 binaries too.

If your project uses Android build scripts like Android.mk system should chose the right tool chain for you.